# What does the "It" in "It's right" refer to?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

At about the 29 minute mark in *Zack Snyder's Justice League (2021)* -- during the scene where Steppenwolf comes for the Mother Box guarded by the Amazons -- Hippolyta snags the Box with a lasso just as he's reaching for it, and seconds later,
Epione is knocked down by a blast from one of the Parademons. Hippolyta then approaches her, and Epione says:

> EPIONE: Honor us. **It's right**. Seal it.

What does the "It" in "It's right" refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with what logicdictates said in the previous answer. At about 28 min 36sec one of the Amazonian warriors says "you must seal the cave" to which Queen Hippolyta yells "go" and two warriors rush down the passage way. I believe the "it" refers to this action of sealing the cave and sacrificing those who remain. Allowing the remaining Amazonians to be sacrificed in their duty would bring them great honor, and also save the box from being lost to Steppenwolf. "It's right" is short for "it's the right thing to do".

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right about sealing the "cage" (as it's referred to in the dialogue), or chamber. I'll amend my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

That particular bit of dialogue is very much open to interpretation, so I don't think it's possible to offer an empirically grounded answer here.

My take: in order to decide what Epione meant by "It's right", we first need to decide what she meant by "Honor us" and "Seal it", to put what was said in-between those two statements in it's proper context.

Firstly, what did Epione mean by "Seal it"...? As noted in Scanlan's answer, this is likely a callback to one of the other Amazons stating about a minute earlier that they "must seal the cage", presumably in an attempt to trap Steppenwolf within the chamber. This is indeed what is done as Hippolyta leaves the chamber with the Mother Box.

So what did Epione mean by "Honor us."...? Well, she was seriously injured and quite possibly dying when she made that statement, and I think she'd determined that the Amazons within that chamber were fighting a losing battle, and that those who weren't already dead soon would be (unless they fled, which most of them had no intention of doing). As such, the fate of most of those Amazons was essentially sealed, and Hippolyta could either stay and die alongside them, or leave and try to survive long enough to honor their memory. Epione seemingly wished her to take the latter option.

So when Epione said "Honor us. It's right. Seal it.", I think this was a truncated way of saying "Honor our memory. *It's the right thing to do.* Seal the chamber."